# Converting document collections without partition key to with partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are having production cosmosdb collection WITHOUT PARTITION KEY, now we have decided to introduce PARTITION KEY, it is understood it requires new collection creation with partition key & data migration with production downtime. All our collections having /id property which unique for a given collection. Question is, will /id would be ideal candidate for partition key? if so what are pros & cons?please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have a look at the documentation of choosing partition key from the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey)

If you are going to use id as partition key, you'll need to check/understand if you are querying data on a property other than id, since you will be forced to do a cross-partition query. If not Id would be a good selection as Partition Key

Comment: In my application, it is very much possible to perform querying data on a property other than id but I believe enabling cross-partition = true will be efficient enough. Another point to consider, if I introduce any other property as partition key then id wont be unique across the collection remember we are already having  production data which needs to be migrated from non partition collection to partitioned collection.

Comment: Also your reply sounds like cross-partition query is not MS recommended one but MS recommends to spread the data as much as possible across as many as partition it takes without any limits. Correct me if Im wrong.